# Using multiple select boxes to filter MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table echo'd by PHP which displays all my data. I'm trying to get the data to filter based on dropdowns and a submit button. Each individual dropdown query works 100%...just on their own without an elseif. i.e. if I test them one by one and comment out the others the filter works, just not when they're all uncommented. Here's my code:

```
if ($_POST['raceName']!="Select a race") {
                $raceName = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["raceName"]);
                $filter = "SELECT a.MembershipID, a.FirstName, a.Surname, t.RaceID, t.Time, r.RaceID, r.RaceName, r.Distance, r.ClubYear
                            FROM Athlete AS a 
                            INNER JOIN Time AS t  
                                ON a.MembershipID=t.MembershipID
                            INNER JOIN Race AS r
                                ON t.RaceID=r.RaceID
                            WHERE r.RaceName= '$raceName'
                            ORDER BY a.Surname";
            } elseif ($_POST['athlete']!="Select an athlete") {
                $athlete = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["athlete"]);
                $firstWord = explode(' ',trim($athlete));
                $firstName = $firstWord[0];
                $lastWord = explode(' ', $athlete);
                $surname = array_pop($lastWord);
                $filter = "SELECT a.MembershipID, a.FirstName, a.Surname, t.RaceID, t.Time, r.RaceID, r.RaceName, r.Distance, r.ClubYear  
                            FROM Athlete AS a 
                            INNER JOIN Time AS t  
                                ON a.MembershipID=t.MembershipID
                            INNER JOIN Race AS r
                                ON t.RaceID=r.RaceID
                            WHERE a.FirstName= '$firstName' AND a.Surname = '$surname'
                            ORDER BY a.Surname";
            } elseif ($_POST['distance']!="Select a distance") {
                $distance = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["distance"]);
                $filter = "SELECT a.MembershipID, a.FirstName, a.Surname, t.RaceID, t.Time, r.RaceID, r.RaceName, r.Distance, r.ClubYear 
                            FROM Athlete AS a 
                            INNER JOIN Time AS t  
                                ON a.MembershipID=t.MembershipID
                            INNER JOIN Race AS r
                                ON t.RaceID=r.RaceID
                            WHERE r.Distance= '$distance'
                            ORDER BY a.Surname";
            } elseif ($_POST['clubYear']!="Select a club year") {
                $clubYear = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["clubYear"]);
                $filter = "SELECT a.MembershipID, a.FirstName, a.Surname, t.RaceID, t.Time, r.RaceID, r.RaceName, r.Distance, r.ClubYear
                            FROM Athlete AS a 
                            INNER JOIN Time AS t  
                                ON a.MembershipID=t.MembershipID
                            INNER JOIN Race AS r
                                ON t.RaceID=r.RaceID
                            WHERE r.ClubYear= '$clubYear'
                            ORDER BY a.Surname";
            } else {
                $filter = "SELECT a.MembershipID, a.FirstName, a.Surname, t.RaceID, t.Time, r.RaceID, r.RaceName, r.Distance, r.ClubYear 
                                FROM Athlete AS a 
                                INNER JOIN Time AS t  
                                ON a.MembershipID=t.MembershipID
                                INNER JOIN Race AS r
                                ON t.RaceID=r.RaceID
                                ORDER BY a.Surname";
            }

            $result = $mysqli->query($filter);
```

As you can see I'm combining them with elseif's because I have the intention of combining the queries so the user can use any number of dropdowns to filter. Right now I'd just like each one to work on their own but using this elseif method. At the moment, this code works for the raceName, but for nothing else. It just returns a blank table. Any ideas?

Comment: So you're saying if you select an "Athlete", it's just rendering a blank table? Have you tried checking if it's running the right query in that case. Maybe try a simple `echo $filter`?

Answer (score 0):

Because the first bit of code runs it doesn't get to the elseif's. Try a switch statement instead, or just take out the else's

Comment: Removing the elseif's makes none of them work. I don't think a switch statement is applicable here, because eventually I want it so the user can select multiple dropdowns instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by instead of checking if the dropdown equaled what the dropdown said, check if the dropdown is null. I then removed the else statements and combined the queries. Full code below:

```
$query = "SELECT a.MembershipID, a.FirstName, a.Surname, t.RaceID, t.Time, r.RaceID, r.RaceName, r.Distance, r.ClubYear
                            FROM Athlete AS a 
                            INNER JOIN Time AS t  
                                ON a.MembershipID=t.MembershipID
                            INNER JOIN Race AS r
                                ON t.RaceID=r.RaceID";
            if ($_POST['raceName']!= null) {
                $raceName = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["raceName"]);
                $filter = " WHERE r.RaceName= '$raceName'";
                $query .= $filter;
            } 
            if ($_POST['athlete']!= null) {
                $athlete = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["athlete"]);
                $firstWord = explode(' ',trim($athlete));
                $firstName = $firstWord[0];
                $lastWord = explode(' ', $athlete);
                $surname = array_pop($lastWord);
                $filter = " WHERE a.FirstName= '$firstName' AND a.Surname = '$surname'";
                $query .= $filter;
            } 
            if ($_POST['distance']!= null) {
                $distance = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["distance"]);
                $filter = " WHERE r.Distance= '$distance'";
                $query .= $filter;
            } 
            if ($_POST['clubYear']!= null) {
                $clubYear = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["clubYear"]);
                $filter = " WHERE r.ClubYear= '$clubYear'";
                $query .= $filter;
            }

            $fullquery = $query . " ORDER BY a.Surname";

            $result = $mysqli->query($fullquery);
```

Only thing to figure out now, is how to insert an "AND" between the WHERE queries if there is more than one.